# C strcmp() with one char difference

Tags: c, strcmp

My question is that how will `strcmp()` handle the following case:

```
strcmp("goodpassT", "goodpass");
```

I read that the comparison continues until a different character is found or null character (`\0`) is found in any of the strings. In the above case, when it encounters `\0` for the second argument, will it just stop comparison, or will it still compare to the `T` character ? The return value is 1, but I'm not sure about the stopping condition.

Comment: See [strcmp(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcmp.3.html) and study the source code of `strcmp` in [GNU libc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/), which is [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html)

Comment: forget for a second about all the implementation details. `strcmp` does a lexicographical comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comparison is done using unsigned char. Thus the *shorter string is smaller* as its terminating 0 is smaller than other unsigned nonzero char in the longer string.
See [http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.24.4p1](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.24.4p1)

Comment: I think it's also important to point out http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.1 which says that "A string is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by **and including** the first null character" which makes it clear that the null character is included in the comparison.  Whether the comparison stopped at the character before the null seemed to be the main concern in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The answer for this function strcmp("goodpassT", "goodpass"); will be 1 only.The point upto which lengths of both the string are same will be compared on the basis of their ASCII value.